# C# multi-lists foreach compare

Tags: c#, list, foreach, compare

I want to compare a value and a value of an object in a list...
and be able to use it with others object type lists.

like :

```
ID = generateID();
CheckUsableID(ID, TeamList); 
// or CheckUsableID(ID, PlayerList);
```

Please help me !

```
// C# Code
public bool CheckUsableID(int id, List<object> list)
    {
        foreach(var object in list)
        {
            if (list<object>.id == id)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

            return true;
    }
```

I just want to compare them.

Comment: You should just have `(if object.id==id)`

Comment: Is your `TeamList` *really* a `List<object>`? Not, say, a `List<Player>` or something similar? That's the first thing to fix... and then the syntax of your foreach loop and `if` condition.

Comment: @eddie_cat: Except that `object` is a keyword, and with a `List<object>` there isn't an `id` member available...

Comment: Right you are. Well, upon renaming that `var` to a non-keyword and changing the List to hold whatever the actual type is, OP will still need to change that syntactic bit.

Comment: yeah, i know just write it like that to simplify and easy understanding

Comment: Your `List<object> list` ahould actually be `List<TeamList> list`

Comment: but is that possible to have it work with multi-list ?

Comment: You mean a List of Lists? That is nothing special.

Comment: Have you used a `List<object>` because you want to _be able to use it with others object type lists_? If so, it sounds like you need generics - `public bool CheckUsableID<T>(int id, List<T> list){..}`

Comment: Post the code to your classes. This problem could probably be solved using inheritance, and having the Base class contain the ID. That way you could pass in a List<childClass> and accept a List<baseClass> as an parameter. That way, either type of list you pass will work.

Comment: its for my school project.. i generate an ID and then i check if the ID already exist in a obj of a list... and be able to use it with different lists ! (in different classes)

Comment: @Rahul I doubt OP wants a `List<TeamList>` ... `TeamList` is already a list that needs to be enumerated. OP Probably wants `List<Team>` (your comment suggests a structure like `List<List<Team>>`) - by "multi-list", I'm assuming OP is referring to having a single function be able to work on both types `TeamList` and `PlayerList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use reflection. Here you go with your modified sample !

```
// C# Code
public bool CheckUsableID(int id, List<object> list)
{
    foreach (var obj in list)
    {
        var objId = (int)GetValueFromObj(obj, "id");
        if (objId == id)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private object GetValueFromObj(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj);
}
```

Comment: look really good .. i will try this  ! thx

Comment: @MHX This is overkill for the problem as described. You would be better off extracting an interface from your `Team` and `Player` objects (i.e. `interface IHasId { int id { get; } }`)

Comment: THANKS TO YOU !! i dont knew that you could do that ! i just recently start my c# course and it doesnt seem to appear in the book that we can do that !!

Comment: ok thx, i will read more about interface  !! lol

Comment: @ MHX as @Michael have said Reflection needs to be used with care. You should do it only if you have no other options left, for e.g. you are handling an anonymous object or receiving a POJO in your WebAPI service and have any other practical limitations to not modify your design. Mark this as an answer if it really have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use LINQ? There's no need to loop through the entire list. Let Linq do the dirty work for you.

```
bool hasUsableID = TeamList.Any(t => t.Id == ID);
bool hasUsableID = PlayerList.Any(p => p.Id == ID);
```

I'm assuming

- TeamList is a List< Team > and Team has the property ID exposed
- PlayerList is a List< Player > and Player has the property ID exposed

Comment: look way easier, but i cant use linq in this class project :S

Comment: That's dumb. Are you going over a specific subject in class that specifies how you should handle this problem? You're teacher can't expect you to know about reflection (as your answer shows) and use it rather than using LINQ.

Comment: i think im not suppose too go that far, cause i just start c# .. and linq is at the end of my book so .. i think its for later , but i'll keep your answer for futur project !! XD  THX

Answer (score 1):

In order to check lists of different types you'll need something either an interface or base class that all the objects that could appear in a list implement. When you have that you can use generics when defining the method.

For example, we could define an interface:

```
public interface IDomainObject
{
    int id { get; set; }
}
```

Then we can redefine the method with generics:

```
public bool CheckUsableID<T>(int id, List<T> list) where T : IDomainObject
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        if (item.id == id)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

        return true;
}
```

Assuming that `TeamList` is a `List<Team>` or similar and `PlayerList` is a `List<Player>` or similar you will need to just ensure `Team` and `Player` implement the `IDomainObject` interface and you'll be able to pass them to the CheckUsableID method:

```
List<Team> TeamList = new List<Team>();
//populate TeamList from somewhere
ID = generateID();
CheckUsableID(ID, TeamList);
```

If you create a base class you could then put the method in the base class:

Comment: look really good too , thx to you

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have plenty of syntax errors and improper use of the key words. I will provide you with an example and you can fix it yourself:

In this case, I'm assuming `<object>` is actually a class, right? In that case, you need to redefine the object.

```
public bool CheckUsableID(int id, List<clsSomeObject> someTeamList)
{
    clsSomeObject newObject = new clsSomeObject();
    newObject = someTeamList;

    foreach(var object in newObject)
    {
        if (newObject.id == id)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

        return true;
}
```

Comment: its for my school project.. i generate an ID and then i check if the ID already exist in a obj of a list... and be able to use it with different lists !

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

you Post a list of ID's that you whant to compare, and GET a list with ID.

```
public List<SomeObject > CheckUsableID(int id, List<SomeObject > list) 
{
      var listUsableId = new List<SomeObject >();
      foreach(var object in list)
        {
            if (object.Id == id)
            {
                listUsableID.add(object);
            }
        }
       return listUsableId;

}

public class SomeObject 
{
    public int Id { get; set }
}
```

Comment: no, sorry if i have some trouble to explan it , i speak french... but i want to call this method from an other class !!